# Android writing bitmap to sdcard

Tags: java, android, bitmap, sd-card

I'm trying to write a bitmap to an sdcard on android, and I get the error message of 
`/mnt/sdcard/PhysicsSketchpad/sketchpad145.png (No such file or directory).` 
I declared the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest, and this is my code:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                        "/PhysicsSketchpad/";
File dir = new File(file_path);
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "sketchpad" + pad.t_id + ".png");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

What's going on?

***UPDATE***

It seems as though when I try to write to an existing directory, I get an permission denied error,

```
08-11 09:55:23.796: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(8881): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/download/sketchpad54.png (Permission denied)
```

and when I try to save in a new directory I get a no such file or directory error,
 `08-11 09:59:20.175: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(9040): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/PhysicsSketchpad/sketchpad55.png (No such file or directory)`

In addition, `File.mkdirs()` returns a boolean based on if it succeeded or not, and it returned false.

Comment: I found the problem! My uses permission tags were nestled in my application tag. Although it didn't solve my problem directly, Ilango's answer and comments helped me the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code.

```
  String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                            "/PhysicsSketchpad";
    File dir = new File(file_path);
if(!dir.exists)
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "sketchpad" + pad.t_id + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
```

Comment: Are you trying using emulator or device? If device, have you inserted sdcard or if emulator, have you added sdcard?

Comment: **08-11 00:29:30.116: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(13140): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/PhysicsSketchpad/sketchpad153.png (No such file or directory)** from `catch (IOException e) { Log.w("Physics Sketchpad", "Error when saving: IOException " + e.getLocalizedMessage()); }`

Comment: @Sudar I tried it on both, both of which had an sdcard. The emulator however gave me an access denied error, **08-11 07:55:38.418: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(284): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/PhysicsSketchpad/sketchpad1.png (Permission denied)**

Comment: I could recreate same error message without the following line in androidmanifest.xml : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>, could you please check for this line inside <manifest>?

Comment: try this,  File dir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myDir1"); dir.getCacheDir();  if(!dir.exists()){ dir.mkdirs(); }     File file = new File(dir, "sketchpad" + pad.t_id + ".png");

Comment: @Ilango it gives me the no such file or directory error: **08-11 01:27:26.527: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(6818): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/myDir1/sketchpad53.png (No such file or directory)**

Comment: @Ilango I've tried running in an emulator as well as on devices. See the comment above for the error on an emulator.

Comment: go to in ur emulator settings->sd card phone storage->   what is displaying there mount sd card or un mount sd card?

Comment: @Ilango Sorry, I though the emulator had an SD card but apparently it doesn't. I ran the program in an emulator with one and it gave me the same no such file or directory error that the devices were giving me.

Comment: I found the problem! My uses permission tags were nestled in my application tag. Although it didn't solve my problem directly, Ilango's answer and comments helped me the most.

Answer (score 3):

try this code. This has worked for me.

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bm)
{
    try
    {
        String mBaseFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
        String mFilePath = mBaseFolderPath + "abcd.jpg";

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(mFilePath);
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Could not save", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Shash

Comment: Can you share the logcat message ? Does /mnt/sdcard/PhysicsSketchpad folder exist ?

Comment: Sorry, about the above post, it's a different error with your code. In the IOException catch I wrote: `Log.w("Physics Sketchpad", "Error when saving: IOException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());`, which gave a logcat message of **08-11 00:27:04.326: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(12994): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/sketchpad152.jpg (Permission denied)**. With the other code I get the error message of **08-11 00:29:30.116: WARN/Physics Sketchpad(13140): Error when saving: IOException /mnt/sdcard/PhysicsSketchpad/sketchpad153.png (No such file or directory)**

Comment: Does your SD Card have DCIM/Camera directory ?

Answer (score 0):

you getting the absolute path check into the error what you getting the path

```
/mnt/sdcard/AppName/appname145.png
```

and you set the

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                        "/PhysicsSketchpad/";
```

where as "PhysicsSketchpad" dir not getting in above path

try this

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/PhysicsSketchpad/";
```

Comment: I tried to edit out the name of my program in the code to make it more general, but I forgot to change it for half of it. I edited it back.